# Use of String replacement methods skipping some records

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I used string replacement methods in my code to display the HTML code correctly on a web page. But it resulted in some erratic behavior. The HTML code is now displaying correctly on web pages, but some records are missing. Now all records in the database are not being displayed. Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <%
        List<TextBean> list = TextDAO.getData();
        for (TextBean pb : list) {
            if((pb.getText().contains("<"))||(pb.getText().contains(">"))){
                //These two lines are causing problems. If I remove them, all records are displayed.
                pb.setText(pb.getText().replaceAll("<", "&lt;"));
                pb.setText(pb.getText().replaceAll(">", "&gt;"));

            }
            %>
            <div id="qa" name="qa" style="min-height: 4px; height: auto; width: 750px;margin: 0 auto;background-color:#f0f0f5;">
                <%=pb.getText() %>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <%
        }
    %>
</body>
```

The solution of one problem is causing me another. If I remove the string replacement methods all records are displayed, but the HTML code becomes the corresponding page. If I use them, not all records are displayed. What kind of bug it is?

Comment: Can you include example of the records you want to display and which of them are missing after 'conversion'?

Comment: It is not possible. I deleted all records to rectify the problem. But it skipped the non html code records after conversion.

Comment: Use of these lines sometimes results in Null pointer exception also.

Comment: without you giving an example of working vs nonworking data there's no reliable way to help you. Also, if you have a nullpointer exception: Which line is it in - what variable is most likely null?

Comment: It gives null pointer exception where the TextDAO.getData() method is called. However it was because my Wmd-Master editor was sending null values. And as I told the records in which there was no html coding were not being displayed. Here is my code of getData() method:-

Comment: rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM QNAS");
            while (rs.next()) {
                TextBean bean = new TextBean();
                bean.setText(rs.getString(1));
                //bean.text=bean.text.replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
                //bean.text=bean.text.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
                list.add(bean);
            }

Comment: The nullpointer exception could  be caused because pb is `null` or the text within the `TextBean` is null. To fix this you could surround `if((pb.getText().contains("<"))||(pb.getText().contains(">"))){` with the following: `if ((pb != null) && (pb.getText() != null)) {`. Are the records you are missing containing text and/or `<` and/or `>`?

Comment: Mostly missing records do not contain </>. It is some random behavior. Sometimes some records containing </> were also missing. What  you want me to do is:-  if ((pb != null) && (pb.getText() != null)) {if((pb.getText().contains("<"))||(pb.getText().contains(">"))){}}

Comment: Thanks its working :)